# Silverlight Rounding Corners

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-3.0

I have a Grid with various child elements like Grid, Stackpanel, **Image**...Is it possible to round the corners of the grid in a way that crops ALL of the contents? Additionally, the root Grid can vary in size so that cannot be hard coded.

**Edit:** After a great deal of searching I found that the best solution for this problem is using ClippingBehavior as susggested by @wdavo, thanks! The real problem is not knowing the dimensions of the image. If you know the dimensions then there are many simple out of the box solutions out there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this clipping behavior

http://expressionblend.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/61176#494852

You'll need the Expression Blend SDK installed

```
<UserControl
x:Class="RoundedCorners.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
xmlns:behaviors="clr-namespace:Expression.Samples.Interactivity"
xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"
mc:Ignorable="d"
d:DesignHeight="800"
d:DesignWidth="800">
<Grid
    x:Name="LayoutRoot"
    Background="White"
    Margin="50">
    <Grid
        Background="LightGreen">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition
                Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
            <behaviors:ClippingBehavior
                CornerRadius="30" />
        </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <Image
            Grid.Row="0"
            Stretch="Fill"
            Source="Image.JPG" />
        <StackPanel
            Grid.Row="1">
            <TextBlock
                Text="Hello" />
            <TextBlock
                Text="World" />
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by inserting the grid or stack panel to a border control just like the code below:

```
         <Border CornerRadius="5,5,0,5" BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="Black" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="100" Height="100" VerticalAlignment="Center">
             <StackPanel>
                 <StackPanel.Background>
                     <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                         <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="0"/>
                         <GradientStop Color="#FF030FC6" Offset="0.2"/>
                     </LinearGradientBrush>
                 </StackPanel.Background>
             </StackPanel>

         </Border>
         <Border CornerRadius="5,5,0,5" BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="Black" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="100" Height="100" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="68.833,0,0,0">
             <Border.Background>
                 <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                     <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="0"/>
                     <GradientStop Color="#FFE90D0D" Offset="1"/>
                 </LinearGradientBrush>
             </Border.Background>
             <Grid/>
         </Border>
```

Comment: -1 if there is an Image tag in the container then it doesn't get cropped and that was an important part of the question. That's why I made Image bold. Thanks for taking a stab though!